# Counting apples

Tags: combinatorics

A group of 10 friends stands in a circle. Initially, one person has 200 apples, and
no one else has apples. The friends split the apples according to the following rules:

• sharing: to share, a friend passes two apples to the left and one apple to the right.

• eating: the apples must also be eaten and enjoyed. However, no friend wants to be
selfish and eat too many apples. Every time a person eats an apple, they must also
pass another apple to the right.

A person may only share if they have at least three apples, and they may only eat if they
have at least two apples. The friends continue sharing and eating, until so many apples
have been eaten that no one is able to share or eat any more. How many apples are there which can no longer be eaten?

Comment: Apples or mangoes?

Comment: @saulspatz oh sorry it's apples

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  What's the sequence of events?  Say one person started with exactly $3$ instead of $200$.  What happens?  The person could share or they could eat.  How do they choose which to do?

Comment: In the worst case all ten end up with one apple each, leaving $10$ apples uneaten.  Is this the only case?

Comment: Without an additional rule that decides whether a given person will share or eat at any given time, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: In the worst case all ten end up with one apple each, leaving 10 apples uneaten. Is this possible? If everybody always chooses "eat" when they can, I think there are $3$ apples uneaten at the end, related to one hundred being written as $1100100_2$ in binary

Comment: @Nij  Are you sure of that?  Perhaps the final count is independent of the choices made.  That is certainly the case for small starting numbers.  Granted, the OP should clarify the point.  Is it the case that the person may chose to either eat or share at will?

Comment: The rules should be clear inside the instructions, we have rules about eating apples stated in the question.

Comment: @lulu: In the case of $3$, the outcome will be $1$ apple eaten and $2$ uneaten, no matter what choices are made when choices can be made

Comment: @Henry  Exactly. and, if I didn't mess it up, starting with $4$ the outcome is also independent of the choices.

Comment: For small starting numbers, sure, the choice graph might have a single sink. This may not be the case for larger starting numbers, or it is possible that 200 is the weird number. Extrapolation from small cases can be useful for intuition; it can also be extremely misleading. @lulu

Comment: @MathForEver  No, the rules are not clear.  As I asked before, suppose one person has exactly $3$.  What do they do?  Are they free to choose whether to share or to eat or is their choice determined somehow?

Comment: We have rules for what happens **if** a person eats an apple. We **do not** have a rule for deciding whether a person eats or not. Therefore the question is not clear.

Comment: The person can choose between eating an apple or sharing.

Comment: Exactly. *So **how** do they decide?!*

Comment: They choose randomly (or it is up to you to find what they decide)

Comment: @MathForEver  If the person may chose at will, or randomly, fine.  But please edit your post to clarify that.  As you see from  the comments, the point is not at all clear.  The key issue, in this case, is "is the final count independent of the choices made?"  It simply isn't obvious.

Comment: Randomly on what distribution?

Comment: I guess $1/2$ I'm not entirely sure myself (that's why I'm asking)

Comment: @MathForEver  I suspect it makes no difference.  I think that's the point.  Let's just say each person can choose however they like.

Comment: So you've asked a question with insufficient information to be answered, because you expect us to have that information?

Comment: The way I would proceed:  first determine the answer, assuming one exists.  Do this by using the "pure share" choice function.  Always share if you can. Eat only if you have exactly $2$. Then I would test the theory by using the "pure eating" strategy.  Always eat if you can.  Trusting that these match, at least the problem will have been clarified.

Comment: @Nij well the source is from a reliable competition. (I found a similar source here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550334/new-zealand-imo-training-2011-combinatorics-cookie-passing?rq=1)

Comment: The problem you linked to is extremely different. It asks for the minimum number of cookies on an even-numbered circle of people such that every person is passed a cookie.

Comment: I mean of course it’s an IMO preparation problem, this problem is linked pretty closely with that one though.

Comment: @Henry why would binary work? I think you’re right.

Comment: @MathForEver With the "always eat" option, you are sending half the apples one step to the right and destroying the other half, possibly with a remainder.  It is these remainders which represent the binary $1$s

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is to prove that the final number of apples (in fact, the final configuration of apples) is independent of the sequence of moves used to get there.

Hint: suppose that in a particular sequence of moves you share at some point, and the person to your left's next action is to eat an apple. The combined effect of these two moves is that one of your apples is eaten (it doesn't matter who eats it) and one of them is moved to the person to your right. So this sequence of moves has the same final outcome as some other sequence with fewer moves.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by this... would it be possible to elaborate?

Comment: Yeah same with @OmriconGamma

Comment: I believe the question remains unanswered. Anyone care to give it another attempt?

Comment: \bump. Are there any more developments about this problem?

Comment: @OmicronGamma I believe my hint is sufficient to allow people to figure out the complete solution. I'm not going to post the full solution on the grounds that the question lacks context. (I thought it was interesting enough that I chose to provide a hint rather than voting to close, but I can see why others have done the latter.)